# How can one construct a phase space for the time evolution trajectories in Hamiltonian?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, stability

I was wondering if conjugate momenta and position can be the variables of the phase space or not.

I have $\frac{\mathrm{d}x_1}{\mathrm{d}t}$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}x_2}{\mathrm{d}t}$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}p_1}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}p_2}{\mathrm{d}t}$ time evolutions and derivative of $x_1$ is equal to $x_2$.

Can one consider $\frac{\mathrm{d}x_1}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}p_1}{\mathrm{d}t}$ in two dimensional phase space while also considering $\frac{\mathrm{d}x_2}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}p_2}{\mathrm{d}t}$ in a two dimensional phase space and then try to draw the trajectories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to consider :

1. Yes conjugate momenta and positions can be variables of the phase space. But their derivatives shouldn't : variables can describe the phase space only if they arise from  a canonical transformation and thus preserve the hamiltonian structure of dynamic. In other words a hamiltonian must exists for these new variables. A way to find such transformation might be to use a generating function.
2. You can draw a subset of the phase space knowing that it is of dimension 4 and so undrawable in reality. You can for instance make a projection on the plane $(x_1, p_1)$ and another on $(x_2,p_2)$ like you the good suggestion you did but without the derivatives. This is a classic way to deal with it.